# How to check app.request.attributes.get('_route')==blog/slug variables

Tags: symfony, twig

For eg if my url is
http://localhost/project/blog
We can check current url with routes by

```
 {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'blog' %}
</p>this is default page</p>
    {%endif%}
```

BUt  for below url:
http://localhost/project/blog/2
this is not working

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'blog/2' %}
</p>this is blog page 2</p>
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Print it if you're not sure what's there `{{app.request.attributes.get('_route')}}`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This seems like something you should manage in the controller.

Comment: if i go to http://localhost/project/blog/2 i want to have another view but it is giving me same view " this is default page"

Comment: You can get slug param from request.
`app.request.get('slug')` or other param ofcourse.

Comment: @karol thanks i tried and it worked
 {% if app.request.get('page') == '2' %}
    </p>this is blog page 2</p>
{% else %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **app.request.requestUri**: should return "project/blog/2"

```
{% if 'blog/2' in app.request.uri  %}
    </p>this is blog page 2</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: its not working if i write like this 
 {% if app.request.uri('_route') == 'blog/2' %}
<p>this is 2</p>
{% else  %}

Comment: thanks its similar to 
{% if app.request.get('page') == '2' %} </p>this is blog page 2</p> {% else %}